# How to make a paragraph at the beginning a section?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I have a problem with paragraphs. Well, I want every sentence that starts a new chapter or sub-chapter to have a paragraph. I still know how to make a paragraph. It is enough to give a blank line. E.g. *UML (Unified Modeling Language) sentence is a technological technology for modeling* should have a paragraph, but not there. Maybe someone knows how to do it?

```
\ section {Application Modeling Technology}
\ subsection {UML language}

UML (Unified Modeling Language) is a technological technology for modeling. Modeling to the 
process by which we design the application, the presented application ~ \ cite {uml}.
The creators who created the UML were G. Booch, I. Jacobson and J.Rumbaugh ~ \ cite {uml2}.

In UML we can create 13 diagrams. They are divided into 3 main groups. To the first graphic 
group that represents a static application
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{identfirst}`. (It is quite common not to indent after \section as you don't need it to identify the start of a paragraph there.).

Comment: That's work. Thanks.

Comment: It is traditional that the first line after a sectional title is not indented. By definition the line after the title is the first line in a paragraph.